# How to save a bearer token in front end from a url query string? RESTful api in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, rest

My application has local login and authentication in its WebAPI.
Regular login would save the bearer token in a session after verifying the users password and username client side. I did so with axios.

Now i want a passwordless login for the users, by sending them a login link via email. I have written code in my WEBapi that generates a Bearer Token for the user. Ready to be sent and saved to a session.

I am not sure what to do next. I want my application to stay RESTful and not handle any sessions backend.

I could give the user a link with the Token as a query string. How can i write a front end script that would receive the token on load?

What other solution are there?

Comment: sessioStorage, localStorage, cookies...

Comment: I did not phrase my question right i think. If I include the token in the URL, like: www.website.com/home?Token=token.

How do I write javascript that checks if the Token is there on entry, and saves it to sessionStorage if it is.

Comment: @Thorbear Here  you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @vladimir-bogomolov This is it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function which is fired as soon as application loads and store the Token from query string in your localStorage or sessionStorage or indexedDB.

Comment: Yes, this is it.
Using the link provided by @vladimir-bogomolov solved my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript